# How to multiple elements of two lists without using a for loop?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

Here is a simple example. How can I perform -a[[ith element]]*b[[ith element]], with i=1:4 without using a for-loop? Thanks so much!

```
a = list(
  c(1, 2),
  c(2, 7),
  c(5, 3),
  c(1, 4))
  
b = list(
matrix(1:4, 2, 2),
matrix(7:10, 2, 2),
matrix(2:5, 2, 2),
matrix(40:43, 2, 2))
```

OPERATIONS:

```
-a[[1]]*b[[1]]
-a[[2]]*b[[2]]
-a[[3]]*b[[3]]
-a[[4]]*b[[4]]
```

DIMENSION of FINAL OUTPUT: 4 x 2 x2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `Map` to do elementwise operations between corresponding list elements

```
Map(`*`, a, b)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    4    8

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   14   18
[2,]   56   70

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   20
[2,]    9   15

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   40   42
[2,]  164  172
```